# CakePHP 2.1 .po files / translation not working

Tags: cakephp, translation, cakephp-2.1

I use `<?php echo __("this is my string"); ?>` inside my views to display text in multiple languages. I created a .po-file directory for german:

=> app/Locale/ger/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

> msgid "this is my string"
>
> msgstr "dies ist meine zeichenkette"

When I add `Configure::write('Config.language','ger');` to my AppController.php beforeFilter function the text still remains "this is my string". Even if I create a .po for english with a different msgstr the text still remains the same.

Do I have to change a specific setting to activate the translation?

---

I have a follow up problem: I added `Configure::write('Config.language','eng');` to **core.php** to set my default language but now I can't change the value, even if I try to override it in **AppController.php** beforeFilter with:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu'); //'de' also doesn't work
CakeSession::write('Config.language', 'deu'); //'de' also doesn't work
```

If I change the value in core.php it works perfectly fine but once set in core.php I cant change it.

**solved:** ah, I forgot to add `parent::beforeFilter();` inside the beforeFilter function of all the controllers.

---

**Additional information:**

- If you want to define a default language (and you usually will), add `Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');` to the **core.php**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at the file lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php, to know how to call each language.

settings for German:

```
Configure::write('Config.language','de');
```

=> app/Locale/deu/LC_MESSAGES/default.po

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the L10n.php file, I will use that for future references.

Answer (score 6):

its "deu" not "ger"

CakePHP uses the official (T) codes from http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php, for CakePHP 1.3 it is documented under [Internationalizing Your Application](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html#internationalizing-your-application):

> The three-character locale codes conform to the [ISO 639-2](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) standard, although if you create regional locales (en_US, en_GB, etc.) cake will use them if appropriate.

```
ISO 639-2 |  ISO 639-1 | English name | French name | German name |
Code      |  Code      | of Language  | of Language | of Language |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ger (B)   |            |              |             |             |
deu (T)   |  de        | German       | allemand    | Deutsch     |
```

Comment: Ah, now it works. Wasn't obvious to me that I have to use the "T" value from the file, too bad that this is not mentioned in the documentation as I think a lot of other CakePHP users might not know that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can only mark one as the correct answer, I took del_dan's one because of the reference to the L10n file.

Comment: no problem. as for the documentation: you can participate by pushing to the github rep: https://github.com/cakephp/docs - so you can put the missing information in.